# How do I add the ToggleSwitch control in Windows Phone 8 to the toolbox (Visual Studio 2013)

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

From NuGet I added the most recent Windows Phone ToolKit to my solution.  I also checked the object Browser and the ToggleSwitch control is definitely there, but I can't add it to my Toolbox (doesn't show up as one of the controls from Choose Toolbox Items...) and also when I start typing on the Xaml page the closest that appears is the ToggleButton.

I added this already to my phoneapplicationpage

```
xmlns:tk="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
```

So I'm not sure where to go from here

EDIT: figured out from xaml I'm supposed to do this

```
<tk:ToggleSwitch></tk:ToggleSwitch>
```

But I still can't get it into the toolbox if that's even possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to add Controls to ToolBox, - here is [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff462023%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

It goes like this:

1. Open TootBox,
2. Right Click on 'Common Windows Phone Controls' (for example),
3. Click on 'Choose Items',
4. You can Browse for your dll and add it,
5. Mark Controls you wish to add.